# Adding a URL to an Iframe being called by Fancybox2-AJAX Based on the Iframe's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox-2

Okay I have this working minus the fact of having this working once I call in with fancybox via AJAX.

Static Example Works:

```
 <iframe id="videourl1" width="640" height="340" src="" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
 <iframe id="videourl2" width="640" height="340" src="" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
 <iframe id="videourl3" width="640" height="340" src="" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

$("div.video-container iframe").each(function(){var idAdd=$(this).attr("id");$(this).attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idAdd+"?rel=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1")})
```

Now when I take this and pull the 3 iframes into .txt files and call them from an index.html file using fancybox2-ajax call it fails:

Index.html:

```
  <a id="1" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="text/1.txt">Link</a>
  <a id="2" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="text/2.txt">Link</a>
  <a id="3" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="text/3.txt">Link</a>
```

Text files contain the iframes:

```
  <iframe id="videourl" width="640" height="340" src="" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

How do I code the JS to say run each time when the iframe is called in by AJAX?

Comment: Answer:


`$(".fancybox").fancybox({ afterShow: function() { $("div.video-container iframe").each(function(){var idAdd=$(this).attr("id");$(this).attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idAd‌​d+"?rel=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1")}); } });`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        $("div.video-container iframe").each(function () {
            var idAdd = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).attr("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + idAd‌d + "?rel=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1")
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: wouldn't be easier to link directly to each youtube video and add the class `fancybox.iframe` to the link?

Comment: The fancybox contains three columns. One has a youtube video and the other two content and a image. That's why I don't just link directly to the YouTube video.  Unless I missing something. I really didn't need to make the YouTube link dynamic, but thought it would be easier to edit just changing the id on the iftame vs making sure to match the yt url and pass the strings to yt for the player each time. Especially if someone else edits it. People always forget the rel and then you get unwanted videos or they use a different embed. I wanted to avoid  this ;)

Comment: Hey JFK - being it seems your really good with FB2 I have a new/same issue as above.  When I come into the page with a #hashtag it fires up the FB, but now with the code above it does so without the YouTube video being populated.  Not sure why as I am using the callBack afterShow.  It works if you go to the site then click-but not directly from URL.  Code in next comment....

Comment: `var thisHash = window.location.hash;
 if(window.location.hash) {
 $(thisHash).fancybox().trigger('click');
 }
//Fire Up Fancybox
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
 //Load YouTube ID after AJAX call to TXT Files
        afterShow: function() {
            $("div.video-container iframe").each(function(){var idAdd=$(this).attr("id");$(this).attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idAdd+"?rel=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1")});
        }
    });
`

Comment: Add a separate question for this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960954/fancybox2-ajax-hashtag

Comment: I insist: it would be better to link directly to youtube videos and open them in iframe. I don't see the reason to use overcomplicated calls to text files with iframe codes. But it seems to me you don't want to do it otherwise

Comment: I agree with you, but for this I must open a YouTube video, have a description of the video, and some related links in the pop-up too.  So I can not simplify it to just the YouTube video.  Also, I have several of these on a page - thus having 20+ iframes loading YouTube - that's why I went the AJAX route.  Now dropping in the ID for the YT video instead of just write out each link - that's me trying to avoid writing out the www...rel=0... over and over and possible avoid others leaving off the rel=0.... for the YouTube videos.  Does that make sense why I am doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fancybox callback `afterLoad` to run javascript after the content is loaded.

However, it does seem unnecessary to jump through all these hoops to load a video instead of just using the media helper:

```
<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">Youtube</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        helpers : {
           media : {}
    }
});
</script>
```

});

Comment: There is a lot more going on than just the youtube video.  I have a lot of content and what not being called into the FancyBox with the video also.  Just post the items bare bone.  So I tried adding the afterLoad, which seems to not be working, might be doing it wrong.  Here it is-  
`$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        afterLoad: function() {
            $("div.video-container iframe").each(function(){var idAdd=$(this).attr("id");$(this).attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idAdd+"?rel=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1")});
        }
    });`

Comment: Solved - used FacnyBox's afterShow.