# How to Get FancyBox2 using AJAX to work with Deeplinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox-2, deep-linking

I thought I would attack this question in a different way.  As in how do I get these two to work together?  The hash tag is not working per se - it does open the pop-up, but does not fire the afterShow function to populate the YouTube video id.  If you directly click on the link on the page everything works.

```
//Fire Up Fancybox
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
//Load YouTube ID after AJAX call to TXT Files
    afterShow: (function() {
        $("div.video-container iframe").each(function(){var idAdd=$(this).attr("id");$(this).attr("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+idAdd+"?rel=0&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1")});
    })
});

//Look for Hash in URL to fire Fancybox
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
$(thisHash).fancybox().trigger('click');
}
```

What I am aiming to do is - if I click directly on a FB2 link or come in from a Hash tag it will fire FB2 and then the YouTube URL is populated.  I would also like to clear the hash out of the URL too in case that effects things (not sure).

HTML file on where a bunch of links live to open the below text file vis FB2 ajax
      `<a id="openfancy1" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="text/openfancy1.txt">Open FB</a>`

Text File contains the YouTube video and many divs+content.  This gets called up and populated into the HTML file once the FB2 link is clicked.
     `<iframe id="YouTube ID of Video" width="640" height="340" src="" frameBorder="0"></iframe> more content and divs....`

Comment: `... it does open the pop-up, but does not fire the afterShow function` : ironically you accepted your own answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24922401/1055987 as a working solution. So does it work or not?, otherwise your other answer is also wrong (and deceiving)

Comment: It does fire the afterShow function when you click on the link directly, but not when you come in with a HASH.  So my initial answer was right.  As stated I am trying to get it to work both ways - which is a separate issue.  I appreciate any insight you can give.

Comment: Updated to make it more clear that it does work minus the hash.